# Efficiently implementing arrays of ternary data types in C

Tags: c, arrays, ternary

I need to implement "big" arrays (~1800 elements) of a ternary datatype as runtime-efficiently as possible in C for cryptographic research. I thought of the following:

**Using an array of any-sized integers, using 2 Bits to represent one element each**

So I'd have

```
typedef uint32_t block;
const int blocksize = sizeof(block)<<3;

block dataArray[3]; // 3*32 bit => 48 Elements

uint8_t getElementAt(block *data, int position)
{
    position = position * 2;
    return (data[position/blocksize] >> (position % blocksize)) & 3;
}
```

returning me 0..2 which i can map to my three values.

**Using an array of uint8_t addressing the elementy directly.**

```
uint8_t data[48];
```

Sure, that needs at least four times more RAM but addressing and setting might be more efficient - is it?

Are there any other good possibilities I'm missing or special caveats in any of the two solutions?

Comment: More efficient at what? It doesn't make sense to discuss program efficiency on "generic computer x". Your solution seems sound for smaller systems like embedded systems, but for systems with plenty of RAM you'll likely want to optimize for speed, store each data type in a byte or larger type. An array of `uint_fast8_t` might be the ideal portable choice.

Comment: So, is processing efficiency your primary concern?  If memory/bandwidth was, you could conceivably encode 20 trits in a 32 bit number (3^10 is 59049, 2^16 is 65536) but then setting/getting individual trits is a pain [but you could use a more verbose method to store for processing and then just "serialize" the data to save to disk / send over network

Comment: Profile it yourself and see. Often times, these kinds of things are counter intuitive and you just need empirical data (for instance, effect of caching on your target).

Comment: This assumes `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: Right, edited to "at least four times".

Comment: Question is not clear whether efficiency means performance or memory usage. Access pattern is also important but not mentioned in the question.

Comment: Have you seen the GNU MP Bignum library? It's built for cryptography applications and research, and it may have some useful tools for you: https://gmplib.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on how big the arrays will get, and how you want to optimize. I sketch some scenarios:

## Runtime, small arrays.

Simply use `unsigned long arr[N]`. Reading only on machine word boundaries is the fastest, but uses a lot of memory. When the memory usage gets too big you actually do not want to do this, because cache performance outweighs the aligned reads.

## Runtime, big arrays.

Use `unsigned char arr[N]`. This will give you fast reads/writes at a decent speed.

## Good memory usage, mediocre speed.

Use `unsigned long arr[N]` and store each trit in two bits, unpacking using shifts and masks.

## Better memory usage, slow.

Use `unsigned long arr[N]`, and store floor(`CHAR_BIT * sizeof(long) * log(2) / log(3)`) numbers, by storing digits in base-3. You can pack 20 trits in 32 bits using this method.

## Best memory usage, horrendous.

Store all the numbers as digits in one base-3 number, using a bignum implementation.